# Placing a user's comment in their own post

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, comments

I can't really think of a specific title for this since it's only just grown on me and I can't find anywhere else so rename if needed, and sorry in advance.

---

So I was on this post [I messed up my PC, how to 'reset to factory'](https://superuser.com/questions/1189466/i-messed-up-my-pc-how-to-reset-to-factory) and in the comment, the user named *Steven* indirectly asked if he could give more information by asking a few questions because the question isn't entirely specific

> Basically I want to completely wipe the hard drive and after that install an OS, I can only get into bios, how can I do this?

so the user who posted his issue replied in the comments:

> I can access only the bios and if I try to boot up I just get a black screen and the flicking underscore for when you are typing text but I can't actually do anything. I was trying to install arch linux and it doesn't matter if it's recoverable, I just want to start fresh. I will use Ubuntu for a while before messing with arch again.

My question is: **Are we able to edit his post and paste his extra information there?** Since posts should be as informative and specific as possible to make it easier to fix the problem.

I've considered something that may have answered my own question by saying to myself *"but everyone can see the comment clearly when they visit his post so why would I need to post it again?"*

Can anyone end my dilemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Are we able to edit his post and paste his extra information there?

Sure, that is a good thing to do as comments are not meant to be permanent in the same way that questions or answers are.

However, if you do this, two pieces of advice:

1. State clearly in the edit summary that you are adding info from the OPs comment to the question (otherwise your edit might be rejected).
2. Make sure you fix any other issues with the question, for example spelling mistakes or removing greeting/thanks.

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
>   suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
>   question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
>   reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place**
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

Source [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://superuser.com/help/editing)

Comment: Great! And yeah, I try to make sure I state what I did in the edit summary whenever making edits. Good reminder

Comment: @JordanSavell I've expanded the answer a little to include some text from the help center.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed this:

**"To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place"**

Really useful. My dilemma has ended.